# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Tags: javascript

Нужно было вынести JS скрипт из HTML `<script>` в отдельный файл *(конечно же синтаксис был другой)*, но я получил ошибку ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else*** и ещё попутно ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >***

```js
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName("header").className;
var navText= document.getElementsByClassName("cd-headline").className;
var container =document.getElementsByClassName("container").className;
var top = document.getElementsByClassName("container").scrollTop;
container.onScroll, function({
  if ( top > 150 ){
    nav.css({backgroundColor:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)', height: '50px'});
    navText.css({opacity: '0', marginTop: '-2em'});
  } else if ( top < 149 )
  {
    nav.css({backgroundColor:'rgba(223, 0 ,79, 0.8)', height: '130px'});
    navText.css({opacity: '1', marginTop: '0.7em'});
  }
});
```

То есть при скролле блока *container* должны меняться css свойства объектов класса *header* и *cd-headline*

В JS я не особо силён, по этому решить самостоятельно не получилось.

До переноса код был следующим

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var nav = $(".header");
var navText=$(".cd-headline");
$('.container').on('scroll', function(){
  // console.log("12515y1951u");
  var top = $('.container').scrollTop();
  if ( top > 150 ) {
    nav.css({backgroundColor:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)', height: '50px'});
    navText.css({opacity: '0', marginTop: '-2em'});
  } else if ( top <= 150 ){
    nav.css({backgroundColor:'rgba(223, 0 ,79, 0.8)', height: '130px'});
    navText.css({opacity: '1', marginTop: '0.7em'});
});
</script>
```

Comment: а зачем меняли синтаксис, когда переносили?

Comment: первая строка выглядела так ***var nav = $(".header");*** и получаем сразу ошибку "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: ну так правильно, использовалась библиотека, которую вы выкинули. Надо не синтаксис менять, а библиотеку подключить

Comment: @ThisMan то есть того, что она подключена в сам **HTML** мало?

Comment: Не `function({...})`, а `function(){...}`

Comment: нет, смотрите, вы подключаете библиотеку, потом ваш скрипт ( который, не меняя, переносите в отдельный файл )

Comment: А вообще весь код бред какой-то

Comment: @andreymal с вашей правкой получил только **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onScroll' of undefined**.  Бред или нет, но до переноса прекрасно работал

Comment: Ну да, потому что при переносе вы наделали десятки ошибок, не только эту. Если вы не сильны в JS, возьмите любой учебник и изучите

Comment: @andreymal а разве стак нужен не для того, чтобы помочь?

Comment: Да, мы тут именно что помогаем, а не читаем лекции по основам синтаксиса JS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, все очень просто делается в вашем случае.

1 - на странице подключаете `jQuery`, через

```
<script src='path/to/jquery'></script>
```

2 - берет ваш скрипт и **НЕ МЕНЯЯ** переносите в отдельный файл

3 - подключаете этот файл, так же как и `jQuery`

```
<script src='path/to/jquery'></script>
<script src='path/to/file.js'></script>
```

На крайняк, можете оберунуть ваш скрипт в

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var nav = $(".header");
var navText=$(".cd-headline");
$('.container').on('scroll', function(){
  // console.log("12515y1951u");
  var top = $('.container').scrollTop();
  if ( top > 150 ) {
    nav.css({backgroundColor:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)', height: '50px'});
    navText.css({opacity: '0', marginTop: '-2em'});
  } else if ( top <= 150 ){
    nav.css({backgroundColor:'rgba(223, 0 ,79, 0.8)', height: '130px'});
    navText.css({opacity: '1', marginTop: '0.7em'});
});
});
```